# Can't compile executable with CMake

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake

I started with the following directory structure:

```
project
       exec
           executable.exe
       lib
           src
           include
       config
           <cmake-generated config file>
```

I created the library in the `lib/src` folder by using a CMakefile in the `lib/src` folder. The exe would compile.

Then, I moved my CMakeFile up to `/lib`, making sure to change the source file paths to `/src/*`
Now, when I try to compile, all my libraries compile and link fine, but when I try to link the executable, I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lconfig`.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens or how to fix it?

Here is some of my code:

```
./CMakeLists.txt:
     include_directories(config)
     SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
     SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
     ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(libs) #library sources
     ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(exec) #executable sources
             CONFIGURE_FILE(${core_SOURCE_DIR}/config/config.h.in  
                  ${core_SOURCE_DIR}/config/config.h)

 ./libs/CMakeLists.txt:
     file(GLOB src ...)
     file(GLOB header ...)
     add_library(lib ${src} ${header})


 ./exec/CMakeLists:
      add_executable(executable executable.cpp)
      link_directories(${core_SOURCE_DIR}/lib) #not sure if this is required
      target_link_libraries(executable ${lots_of_libs})
```

Every library in `lots_of_libs` can be found as a `.a` file in the `lib` directory

Comment: Can you show the content of your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Yeah. I have lots of libraries so I'll try and keep it brief.

Comment: Can you try to see what happens if you remove the statements `SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)` and   `SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)`

Comment: I still get the same error. I'm confused about the `-lconfig` part. Is `-l` used to link libraries? `config` is just a directory that contains header files, I never used `add_library` on `config`.

Comment: Is config somehow in ${lots_of_libs}?

Comment: When you run `make`, run it as `make VERBOSE=1`.  This will show you the command that CMake is using to compile.  Is the path to your `lib` directory being added with a `-L` flag?

Comment: @StevenMorad First thing to check: Add in exec/CMakeLists.txt this: `message(STATUS "lots_of_libs ${lots_of_libs}")` If `config` is not there, there must be something tricky in your configure file... Some strange linking flag... I do not know exactly, I have never used a configure file...

Answer (score 1):

One problem, probably not risolutive, is this:

```
link_directories(${core_SOURCE_DIR}/lib) #not sure if this is required
```

should be:

```
link_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
```

or:

```
link_directories(${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})
```

Anyway, normally you wouldn't need to add to your link_directories the path to a library that is built within the project, even if you have specified a different LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH

Comment: You never have to specify `link_directories` for targets you build from the same CMake project. CMake is smart enough to figure this out by itself.

Comment: @ComicSansMS You are right, but this doesn't change the fact that line had a wrong path in it. Anyway, I will edit my answer.